# Testing Private Methods in Python: Unit Test or Functional Test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

After reading about testing private methods in Python, specifically referring to [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784519/how-do-i-unit-test-the-methods-in-a-method-object), it appears that it is best to just test the public interface. However, my class looks like this:

```
class MyClass:

  def __init__(self):
    # init code

  def run(self):
    self.__A()
    self.__B()
    self.__C()
    self.__D()

  def __A(self):
    # code for __A

  def __B(self):
    # code for __B

  def __C(self):
    # code for __C

  def __D(self):
    # code for __D
```

Essentially, I created a class to process some input data through a pipeline of functions. In this case, it would be helpful to test each private function in turn, without exposing them as public functions. How does one go about this, if a unit test can't execute the private function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you [CAN access the "private" stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private), can't you? (Or am I missing something here?)

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             pass
...     def __A(self):
...             print('Method __A()')
... 
>>> a=MyClass()
>>> a
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x101d56b50>
>>> a._MyClass__A()
Method __A()
```

But you could always write a test function in `MyClass` if you have to test the internal stuff:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    def _method_for_unit_testing(self):
        self.__A()
        assert <something>
        self.__B()
        assert <something>
        ....
```

Not the most elegant way to do it, to be sure, but it's only a few lines of code at the bottom of your class.

Comment: You should not be putting test code inside production code.

Comment: this is super dangerous way to write your code - there should never be any code inside your production value that is used for testing - at the very least it will provide false positives, at the worst it could lead to said code accidentally being run in production.  Please anyone doing a search for this do not use this answer.

Answer (score 62):

Python does some name mangling when it puts the actually-executed code together. Thus, if you have a private method `__A` on `MyClass`, you would need to run it like so in your unit test:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestMyClass(TestCase):
    def test_private(self):
        expected = 'myexpectedresult'
        m = MyClass()
        actual = m._MyClass__A
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```

The question came up about so-called 'protected' values that are demarcated by a single underscore. These method names are *not* mangled, and that can be shown simply enough:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class A:

    def __a(self):
        return "myexpectedresult"

    def _b(self):
        return "a different result"


class TestMyClass(TestCase):

    def test_private(self):
        expected = "myexpectedresult"
        m = A()
        actual = m._A__a()
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_protected(self):
        expected = "a different result"
        m = A()
        actual = m._b()
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
        # actual = m._A__b() # Fails
        # actual = m._A_b()  # Fails
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, should be the accepted answer

Comment: What about if methods are with single prefix of underscore?

Comment: @JavaSa I've updated the answer to answer that question.

Comment: Thanks @NathanielFord

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should just test the `run()` method. Most classes will have internal methods -- and it does not really matter in this case whether or not all the code in `__A()`, `__B()`, `__C,()` and `__D()` is actually in `run()` or not. If you suspect or find problems, then you might want to switch to your debugger aspect and test the private methods.

Comment: In this case, I would need to initialize my class with the variables, call run, and test the outcome. But what if I want to test each step in run (each step == each function)?

Comment: Then you have to access them as BenDundee explains.

Comment: Since I received a downvote for this answer, I'd like to point out that I had addressed  the question as asked: "In this case, would it be best to test the private functions and not test the public run() function?"

Comment: You were essentially suggesting he skips testing subroutines, though, or only test them manually. This is not a good habit to adopt; unit tests should test as tight a sequence as possible, and your tests (unit and integration) should test with as much coverage as possible. Knowing how to test private and protected methods is therefore useful, and the advice to skip doing so not great.

Comment: OTOH, unit tests should test _behaviour_, not _implementation_, so tests should exercise the public API, not private methods.

Comment: even Private methods should be tested via behavior - testing by behavior *Does not* mean testing from the API end point. It means that the behavior of the unit being tested is tested, not the data being passed to it. Private/Protected functions should be behavior tested and if you have trouble testing them, then you should reconsider how you write your code to make it easier to test.